# C++ vector passed by reference not modified

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, fstream

When I pass a `std::vector<std::string>` by reference to a function which writes to the vector, the called function modifies the vector but the calling function doesn't see the modification.

For example, in the following code, `oData` has a size of 20 but `data` has size 0. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

bool ReadFile(const std::string & iFile, std::vector<std::string> & oData) {

    std::ifstream myfile(iFile);

    if (!myfile.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        std::string line;
        while (getline(myfile, line)) {
            std::cout << line << '\n';
            oData.push_back(line);
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> data;
    ReadFile("numbers.txt", data);

    return 0;
}
```

Note: Using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10

Comment: It should be `ReadFile("numbers.txt", data);`, otherwise it can't compile.

Comment: What you posted couldn't have been the code you tested.  Here is the [Visual C++ online compiler test](http://rextester.com/QWO58204)

Comment: Can we remove the question then ?

Comment: Edited to fix typo

Comment: @Ahmed Your edit just makes it more likely that there is issue with your input file, i.e. cannot be opened or is empty.  In other words, that `push_back()` is never executed.  [See this](http://rextester.com/UYY90994)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for the response. I figured out that the issue was caused by the location of the Breakpoint in Visual Studio debugger.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie this is my first question here... sorry that it's a bit silly ><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the location of the breakpoint in Visual Studio debugger.

Breakpoint after `return`  --> size of data = 0; [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja6hs.png)

Breakpoint before `return` --> size of data = actual size. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcz2B.png)